# passing date value from datetimepicker.js to another custom javascript

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am using the datetimepicker.js script and I am trying to modify it to send the date to another script when the window closes.
Here is the line of code that passes the date:

```
PCellStr="<td "+vColor+" width="+CellWidth+" align='center'>
<font face='verdana' size='2'"+vHLstr1+"<a href=\"javascript:winMain.document.getElementById('"+Cal.Ctrl+"').value='"+Cal.FormatDate(PValue)+"';"+vTimeStr+";  window.close(); \" onclick='winMain.return_date("+Cal.FormatDate(PValue)+")'>"+PValue+"</a>"+vHLstr2+"</font>
</td>";
```

then in my custom script i call:

```
function return_date(mtDate){
alert(mtDate);
```

}

However, this does not produce the value I am looking for, -1999 is what alerts to the screen, while I am expecting like 19-3-2015. I would expect I am not formatting it correctly when it is sent.

Comment: Trying to solve this while waiting for answers, i changed the line: onclick='winMain.return_date("+Cal.FormatDate(PValue)+") to onclick='winMain.return_date(new Date("+Cal.FormatDate(PValue)+")), now at least i get a formatted date, but not the right date.

Comment: More troubleshooting, just sent a blank call to the new function: onclick='winMain.return_date(), and sense this sends the value to <a href=\"javascript:winMain.document.getElementById('"+Cal.Ctrl+"').value='"+Cal.FormatDate(PValue)+"';"+vTimeStr+"; I tried to get the value of that text box in the new function. var jDate = document.getElementById("date_needed").value; however the text box doesnt apear to be populated until after the entire line is processed, so alerting jDate is blank.

Comment: I would like to close this question, I ended up replacing the JavaScript with another as that script was written in 03 and had a bit of outdated code. How would i close the question?